# how to clear edit text one by one character...including special characters?

Tags: android

i have an edit text and it has numbers and special character like 1234-11222
how can i delete the `numbers` and the `-` ?

i have a code and it works fine for alphabets and numbers but it does not work for special characters.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
     aadrclear.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     String textaddress=addr.getText().toString();
     //txtUserName.setText("");
     if (textaddress.length() != 0) {
         textaddress = textaddress.substring(0, textaddress.length() - 1);
         addr.setText(textaddress);
         addr.setSelection(textaddress.length());
     }
}
```

i have an edit text...if i enter numbers a  `- (hyphen)` is placed between 4 numbers.. now if i want to clear using the above code it is not working.. please help

Comment: What is `nameclear`?

Comment: Please develop more your question, is unclear

Comment: please see the edited code and text

Comment: I see nothing strange in your code, characters like `-` are giving you trouble?

Comment: i have a button appended to edit text on clicking the button the text or numbers gets cleared one by one and if the last character is - in edit text it is not getting cleared

Comment: Try to print textaddress after calling to `substring` to see if the string has the right value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be the solution for my understanding over your question.

```
if(textaddress.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
     if(textaddress.getText().toString().charAt(textaddress.getText().toString().trim().length() - 1) != '-') {
            String result = textaddress.getText().toString().substring(0,textaddress.getText().toString().length() - 1);
            textaddress.setText(result);
            textaddress.setSelection(result.length());
    }
}
```

Notify me if it was wrong

`EDIT`

If u also interested in deleting `-` also. Remove the `if condition`.

Now the code will be like.

```
if(textaddress.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
      String result = textaddress.getText().toString().substring(0,textaddress.getText().toString().length() - 1);
      textaddress.setText(result);
      textaddress.setSelection(result.length());
}
```

Comment: i am still getting an error 09-05 16:59:28.607: E/RichInputConnection(937): Unable to connect to the editor to retrieve text... will retry later

Comment: i am adding a - after every 4 digits is there a problem with that?

Comment: No problem at all. Do you wants to add - after every 4 digits automatically?

Comment: yes..if(number.length()==4)
          {
           no.setText(number+"-");
          no.setSelection(no.getText().length());
          }
          if(number.length()==9)
          {
           no.setText(number+"-");
           no.setSelection(no.getText().length());
          }

Comment: Then u need to work in the edittext textchanged listener. Wait i will update it too.

Comment: can you tell me the correct code to insert - after every 4th number

Answer (score 0):

For adding - every 4 digits use this code snipper

```
int offset = 0;
textaddress.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            offset++;
            if (textaddress.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                if (offset == 4) {
                    String result = text_address.getText().toString()
                            .concat("-");
                    textaddress.setText(result);
                    textaddress.setSelection(result.length());
                    offset = 0;
                }

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanku..it is working but ..a - is added after the last four digits also like 1111-1111-1111- ...i dont want the last hyphen what should i do...

Comment: i have given the max length of edit text to 14 and i am getting an error if i place 15 as max lengh the an extra hyphen is inserted...please help